# Possible to have an Intel Edison act as Remote Control for iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, intel-edison, mfi

I am starting to explore working with Bluetooth LE. To that end I am trying to devise a project so I can give myself a goal.

I am using the Intel Edison as my platform and I was wondering: is it possible to use it's Bluetooth LE capabilities to enable it to control the media playback on iOS (8+) -- play, pause, back, next?

I know I need to use the AVRCP profile, etc. I am not concerned with the implementation in this question, I am more concerned with if Apple even allows such a thing if you are not part of the MFi program. I don't want to spend the dev/exploration time if in the end iOS won't allow me to test it out.

Having read this:
https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1

- Headset Remote and Mic feature

Is specifically called out as requiring MFi. I am going to assume that covers anything using the AVRCP Profile, even if it is not specifically a headset?

This link however:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387

Makes no mention of MFi requirements for AVRCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 way to use BT on iOS:

- BTLE is directly accessible through the iOS SDK, therefore, you can do whatever custom actions you want by developing an app
- MFI program allow you to build apps that connect your custom accessories, using classic BT. It is also useful if you want to place a badge on a product packaging (even if it is actually using basic profiles)
- **BT profiles, including AVRCP, are available by default. You do not need MFI to work with them, it is directly handled by iOS, not through an app.**

Also, in the "Not MFI" section:

> "Accessories that use only standard Bluetooth profiles supported by iOS" - https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1